# Operations in digital image processing small project

Tags: python, image-processing

Well, it’s for a friend who had a very difficult year and couldn’t catch up with her college. Now she has this project to finish before Monday and I already tried to help her out with it but I have no experience in this area so, it’d be great if someone will help out with this or even put me on the right track. 
[image]

Reference link: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/AhmedGadFCIT/operations-in-digital-image-processing-convolution-by-example

Comment: Just giving you the heads up now, you're likely going to get downvotes because 1)Stack Overflow is not a coding/hw completion service and 2)You haven't provided any actual code to show you've attempted the problem. I would suggest following the steps provided in the assignment - first start small, and read an image to a `numpy` arr. Then work on the other areas once you have some code to work with. There are a lot of great threads on the site with information on each of these steps that you can reference, and if you really get stuck you can open up a new thread. Best of luck to your 'friend'

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Please add the work your friend has done so far and were exactly she stucks. Without that information, this question will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:
Color images in the RGB space can be converted to grayscale via following formula:

```
1/3 *(R+G+B)
```

where R is the value of the red channel, G is the value of the green channel and B is the value of the blue channel.

If you want to conserve the perceived brightness of the image, you could also use the standard [Rec. 709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709), which would change the used parameters to:

```
0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B
```

A mean filter is a simple [box filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur). That means that for each pixel you have to determine the surrounding pixels and average them. Nothing more. See also [this](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/mean.htm).

For the metioned padding, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling).

Note that color images can be filtered by applying the filter operation on each of its channels separate. After the application of the filter, one has simply to merge the channels again.